# ASP.NET Membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'd like to use the ASP.NET membership provider in the following (low-security) scenario...

My company will create and administer user accounts on behalf of our clients. These accounts will likely be shared amongst several people in the client company (**is that a problem?**).

There will be 2 types of users (2 roles): client and administrator. Administrators are the people within my company that will have special privileges to create client user accounts, etc.

Clients will *not* be able to self-register. They also won't get to choose their own password, and they should not be able to change their password either, since that will just create confusion where several people are sharing the same account.

My internal users (admins) will set the password for each client. Here's the bit I'm struggling with: if a client phones up and asks to be reminded of their password, how can my admin users find out what the password is? **Can I configure the provider to store the password in clear text (or other recoverable form), and if so can I get at the password through the .NET API?**

As I said at the outset, this is a low-security application, and so I plan simply to show the password in the (internal) web page where I have a list of all users.

Comment: Why even have passwords? Why not just require a username and skip storing a password completely?

Comment: @Thomas: I want the usernames to be logical, which would make them very guessable, otherwise I could rely on security through obscurity of the username. Having a password makes it harder to bluff your way in. As I said, these passwords will probably be shared amongst several people within a client organisation, so the possibility of password leakage is high (made worse by the fact that the passwords will remain unchanged for long periods). However, the password still provides a barrier for the 99.99% of people who do not know the password.

Comment: Exactly my point. If the password is going to be passed around like a who--, eh, a lady of the night, at a frat house, you might as well skip the password requirement entirely or use windows authentication. Using plaintext passwords IMO, is the worst solution.

Comment: @Thomas: the password will be passed around a client company, but is far less to be passed from client to client, which is where we want a barrier (more of a picket fence than a wall). Windows authentication is no good - I don't want to have to administer Windows accounts or buy CALs etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do this:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add 
        name="SqlProvider" 
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
        connectionStringName="MySqlConnection"
        applicationName="MyApplication"
        enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
        enablePasswordReset="true"
        requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
        requiresUniqueEmail="true"
        passwordFormat="Clear" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
```

passwordFormat

Specifies the password format. The SQL Server membership provider supports Clear, Encrypted, and Hashed password formats. Clear passwords are stored in plain text, which improves the performance of password storage and retrieval, but is less secure because passwords are easily read if your SQL Server database is compromised. Encrypted passwords are encrypted when stored and can be decrypted for password comparison or password retrieval. This requires additional processing for password storage and retrieval, but is more secure because passwords are not easily deciphered if the SQL Server database is compromised. Hashed passwords are hashed using a one-way hash algorithm and a randomly generated salt value when stored in the database. When a password is validated, it is hashed with the salt value in the database for verification. Hashed passwords cannot be retrieved.

Comment: I personally think storing passwords as clear text is suicidal for your application, but you asked HOW to do it, not IF you should do it, so I am providing you this answer

Comment: thanks. I was at pains to point out that this is *not* meant to be a secure application. The fact that accounts are shared between many individuals, and the fact that passwords will be freely shared by email & phone tells you just how low-security it is. I think the fact that the passwords are in plain text in the DB pales into insignificance compared to the fact that they're also likely to be emailed in plain text, printed out and stuck to the wall.

Comment: re the second part of my question, can I get the password via the .NET Membership API? Or would I have to query the database tables myself?

Comment: @Gary, I am not 100% sure, but I would hazard a guess at yes.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's low security, it's best not to store the password in plain-text. Since you want it to be recoverable, you should look at Encrypting the passwords. By encrypting, it can be reversed back to it's original form with the correct key. Have a look at the Membership section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx#paght000007_membership)

Comment: @superexsl: I understand the arguments against storing in plain text, but I do think that there's no point whatsoever in encrypting them given that I'm going to have to *display* them in the clear anyway (and given that the passwords will be freely shared with several people in the client company). Someone who really wanted to know the password would probably find getting at the database far less convenient than many other "soft" methods.

Comment: @Gary: That's fine. You can store them in plain-text using `Clear` as the passwordFormat (as Mick Walker has shown).